# Оптимизация поиска в неупорядоченном множестве экземпляров пользовательского класса

Tags: c++, поиск, контейнеры

Рассмотрим неупорядоченное множество (unordered set), в котором хранятся экземпляры пользовательского класса, при этом хэширование выполняется только по одному полю этого класса. Чтобы найти нужный элемент, мы применяем алгоритм find. Однако, этот алгоритм требует также полный экземпляр этого класса, а не только одно поле, по которому выполняется хэширование. Вопрос: можно ли как-то избавиться от создания этого служебного экземпляра класса при поиске в неупорядоченном множестве и обойтись только одним полем?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая возможность официально появится только в C++20 через функциональность так называемых *прозрачных* (transparent) хэшеров и компараторов. То есть начиная с C++20 в `std::unordered_set` появятся *шаблонные* версии методов `find`, принимающий на вход любой тип. (Подразумевается, что вы будете передавать туда значение ключа.)

Для других типов контейнеров (например, `std::set`) возможность такого поиска на основе прозрачных компараторов появилась уже в C++14

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using Item = std::pair<int, int>;

struct Comparator
{
  bool operator ()(const Item &lhs, const Item &rhs) const { return lhs < rhs; }

  using is_transparent = void;
  bool operator ()(const Item &lhs, int rhs) const { return lhs.first < rhs; }
  bool operator ()(int lhs, const Item &rhs) const { return lhs < rhs.first; }
};

int main()
{
  std::set<Item, Comparator> s = { { 1, 100 }, { 2, 200 }, { 3, 300 } };
  auto it = s.find(2);
  std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

А вот для контейнеров, базирующихся на хэшах, эта функциональность задержалась до C++20.